# Is there additional fee for free app submit-ion on windows store market

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I read this on wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_Store

"There's a limit of 100 free submissions for free apps; thereafter, there's a fee of $19.99 per submission for free apps"

And need little clarification from peoples that have been submitted free app on this store.

The limit is up to 100 free apps per account, nothing confusing here.

99 $ per account fee, also everything clear :).

But the part it confuses me is the 19.99 $ fee per app submission ?
Is it correct that every time when I submit free app I need to pay additional 19.99 $ :S ?

Thanks for sharing the experience with me

I know it is stupid question but I do not want to spend 100 $ just to answer my question

Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

The 100 limit is for submissions, not apps.
Note:
 - If you submit an app and it fails certification it counts as a submission.
 - If you submit an update to an app it counts as a submission.
 - If you have different XAP files for the WP7.X and the WP8 versions of an app it will count as multiple submissions.

If and when you reach this limit a cheaper option is to have multiple accounts and split submissions across accounts as this will give you another 100 submissions for another $99.

Be realistic about this though. Are you really going to make, the equivalent of, two submissions a week, every week for a year? (Allowing you a 2 week holiday ;))